# Javascript Mini-Max Sum HackerRank problem returns wrong sum?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. In the HackerRank problem, Mini-Max Sum the question is to find the sum of part of an array of 5 numbers. In the example they give you, they show you `arr = [1,2,3,4,5]` the minimum sum would be `1+2+3+4 = 10` and the maximum sum would be `2+3+4+5 = 14`

I'm still new so solving the problem is still sometimes a challenge for me. I came up with this for my first solution:

```
function minMax(arr){

   console.log(arr, 'this is our arr')

   var baseSum = 0
   var minSum = 0
   var maxSum = 0
   var i = null


   for(i=1;i<4;i++){
     baseSum += arr[i]
   }

   console.log(baseSum, 'this is baseSum')
   console.log(minSum = baseSum + arr[0], maxSum = baseSum + arr[4])
}

const numArr = [7, 69, 2, 221, 8974]

minMax(numArr)
```

My thinking is that I could grab the numbers that are consistent between the two variables, grab the first and last number of the array and add those up to get the result. It passed one test but it fails at the listed values at `numArr`, If I add up those last 4 numbers, I get 9266 but the expected value is **9271**.

I spent some time trying to think of a way to refactor it, I knew it wasn't great to begin with but I'm trying!

I came up with this -

```
function minMax(arr){
  if (arr.length > 5){
    return "Too long"
  }

  var minArr = arr.slice(0,4)
  var maxArr = arr.slice(1,5)

  minSum = 0
  maxSum = 0

  for (i=0; i < minArr.length;i++){
    minSum += minArr[i]
  }

  for (x=0; x < maxArr.length; x++){
    maxSum += maxArr[x]
  }

  console.log(minSum, maxSum)
}
```

But it returned the exact same thing as before. So I'm either, not understanding the question (probably what's happening) or the sum is wrong in their expected value. I even just grabbed a calculator and I'm getting 9266 so I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Has anyone run into this and do they have any ideas what is going on?

**UPDATE**

No surprise to myself, I read the question wrong. You are supposed to *sort* the actual array before you get the sum. They don't really state in the question so it's poorly worded imo lol but this is ultimately all I did to get the correct value in case anyone is wondering.

```
if (arr.length > 5){
    return "Too long"
  }



  arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
  });

  var minArr = arr.slice(0,4)
  var maxArr = arr.slice(1,5)

  var minSum = 0
  var maxSum = 0
  var i = null
  

  for (i=0;i<minArr.length;i++){
    minSum += minArr[i]
  } 

  for (i=0;i<maxArr.length;i++){
    maxSum += maxArr[i]
  }

  console.log(minSum, maxSum)

}


const numArr = [7, 69, 2, 221, 8974]

minMax(numArr)
```

This obviously sums up different values so you'll get the correct answer!

Comment: I would consider first sorting the array from highest to lowest or vice versa - then you would easily be able to grab (like you're doing with `slice`) just the highest or lowest X number of values and add them together

Comment: You're trying to solve this as if the input array is always sorted, which is apparently not the case. This is where your confusion comes from.

Comment: Yeah, my confusion is I thought I didn't need to mutate the array in any way, I was only taking the sum of 5 numbers in an array - the first 4 and the last 4. But that is not the case, I read over the question but they don't really explain it very well lol. I made the changes to sort an array as suggested by @decpk which gave me the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question, It is not specified whether the input array will be sorted or not, So the only thing that you are missing is to sort the array in descending order.

**1)** You can first `sort` the array in `ascending` order

```
const clone = [...arr].sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

**2)** the take **`first four sum`**.

```
const minSum = arr.slice(0, 4).reduce(sum, 0);
```

**3)** also take the **`last four sum`**

```
const maxSum = arr.slice(1).reduce(sum, 0);
```

```js
function minMax(arr) {
  const clone = [...arr].sort((a, b) => a - b);
  const sum = (acc, curr) => acc + curr;
  const minSum = clone.slice(0, 4).reduce(sum, 0);
  const maxSum = clone.slice(1).reduce(sum, 0);
  console.log(minSum, maxSum);
}

const numArr = [7, 69, 2, 221, 8974];

minMax(numArr);
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `[...arr].sort(...);`, since `[...arr] == arr`. Instead of that you should sort in place by just doing `arr.sort(...);` That's why your max sum is off because when you use `arr.slice(...)` the programming is reading the unchanged memory of `arr`. I would suggest going with in place sorting since that's the design of the language (same as the underlying language C which uses pointers for passing around arrays instead of value), or you just need to change `arr.slice(...)` to `clone.slice(...)`

Comment: @charlie-map `[...arr]` and `arr` is not equal in JS. Because `[...arr]` is clone of `arr`. You should read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) .

Comment: you're right. My notation is definitely incorrect there. What I mean is that `[...arr]` and `[arr]` are *logically* equivalent, and contain the same values in the same order before a sort. My suggestion would still be to sort in place using `arr.sort(...)` since we don't need a clone of the array. I would agree that if we were to do something destructive to the array but wanted to keep the original, then having a clone may be beneficial.

Comment: It doesn't mention sorting in the problem though. I would say that the HackerRank problem is misleading. If it meant that the numbers should be sorted then it should say so as this is critical to the solution. Otherwise the min / max values are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To continue having something semi-MinMax oriented. I would suggest sorting as a separate step. Then you can have two pointers in the array that move concurrently through the array to count the minimum and maximum:

```js
function rank(arr, low, high) {
  if (arr.length > 5) {
    console.log("Too long");
    return;
  }

  // we reached the fourth value, so we stop
  if (high == 1)
    return [arr[low], arr[high]];

  // continue calculating at further depth
  let minMaxRecur = rank(arr, low + 1, high - 1);
  return [arr[low] + minMaxRecur[0], arr[high] + minMaxRecur[1]];
}

let initialArray = [7, 69, 2, 221, 8974];
initialArray.sort((a, b) => a - b); // sort first

console.log(rank(initialArray, 0, 4));
```

This uses a recursive algorithm to count through the array, but this could of course be much simpler with a single loop that goes through the array like:

```js
function rankLoop(arr) {

  let min = 0, max = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      min += arr[i];
      max += arr[4 - i];
  }
  
  return [min, max];
}

console.log(rankLoop([2, 7, 69, 221, 8974], 0, 4));
```

This again assumes that the array coming in it sorted, which can be seen in my first code snippet. Either of these works with the same time complexity.

Comment: If you sort don't you change the problem and thereby the solution?
Seems like HackerRank needed to make this clearer in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in Python :

```
def miniMaxSum(arr):
    arr.sort()
    hold = [None]*int(len(arr)-3)

    for i in range(0,len(arr)-3):
        temp = 0

        for j in range(i,i+4):
            temp = temp + arr[j]
        hold[i] = temp
    
    print(hold[0],hold[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    
let max = arr[0];
    let min = arr[0];
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if(max< arr[i]){
            max= arr[i];
        }
        if(min> arr[i]){
            min=arr[i];
        }

        sum += arr [i];
        
    }
    let maxSum= sum -min;
    let minSum = sum - max;
    console.log(minSum +" "+ maxSum);}
    
    minMax([your data])
```